# No memoir.sty file?

Tags: packages, memoir, ctan

I am trying to load the Memoir package into my LaTeX document. MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoir}

\begin{document}
\HUGE This command is from the memoir package.
\end{document}
```

How come Overleaf isn't finding the file? Looking at CTAN there isn't an STY file, so I assumed it would just compile it on download (?)

Comment: `memoir` is a class not a package

Comment: @JosephWright How do I import a class? I read that it works for other documentclasses

Comment: `\documentclass{memoir}`, but you can only use one class - it _doesn't_ work with other classes - where did you see that?

Comment: Also, @JosephWright that totally messes up my math. My square root symbol looks... Let's just say interesting.

Comment: Without an example I can't really say, but it sounds like a font setup issue.